# Find all seventh-power residues modulo $29$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find all seventh-power residues modulo $29$.

- I have an indices table to refer to in the back of my book but have to solve this by hand. I am under the assumption this involves Fermat's Little Theorem but still quite lost. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Between this and your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733896/find-all-solutions-to-x9-equiv-25mod-29) from ten minutes ago it really looks like you are just putting your homework up here for us to do for you.

Comment: This is my midterm review and I've gone through it and now posting up the remaining questions I didn't understand. Relax.

Comment: @flawr It's definitely not a duplicate of the other question. You can't solve this with the method used in the main answer of the other question.

Comment: @user236182, indeed, it is "the opposite" of the other question. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett You can vote to reopen then.

Comment: When I made my earlier comment, this question had not been closed...  Just now, I did vote to re-open. It is of course somewhat related to the linked-to question, but strongly _complements_ it, rather than being the same (even if the questioner used the same context-setting language), presumably out of naivete about the situation.

Answer (score 3):

You could check $0^7,1^7,2^7,\ldots, 14^7$ mod $29$. Then $$\{0^7\bmod 29,1^7\bmod 29,2^7\bmod 29,\ldots, 14^7\bmod 29,$$

$$-14^7\bmod 29,\ldots,-2^7\bmod 29,-1^7\bmod 29\}$$

would be your answer. But this could be a bit tedious. Here is another solution:

$a$ is a $7$'th power mod $29$ if and only if $a\equiv x^7\pmod{29}$ for some $x\in\mathbb Z$.

Clearly $0$ is a $7$'th power mod $29$. Let $29\nmid a$. Then if $a\equiv x^7\pmod{29}$ for some $x\in\mathbb Z$, then $a^4\equiv x^{28}\equiv 1\pmod{29}$ by [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

$29\mid a^4-1=(a-1)(a+1)\left(a^2+1\right)$

By [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) this is equivalent to either $29\mid a-1$ or $29\mid a+1$ or $29\mid a^2+1$.

If $a^2\equiv -1\pmod{29}$, then $a^2\equiv 144\equiv 12^2\pmod{29}$, so

$29\mid a^2-12^2=(a+12)(a-12)$. By [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) either $29\mid a+12$ or $29\mid a-12$.

Therefore $\{0,1,-1,12,-12\}$ is your answer, or i.e. $\{0,1,12,17,28\}$.

---

$a^2\equiv -1\pmod{29}$ had a solution because $29$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$.

$a^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ would have no solutions if $p$ were a prime of the form $4k+3$. See [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) for more general results.