# Find all solutions $x^{40} \equiv 2 \pmod {79}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all solutions $x^{40} \equiv 2 \pmod {79}$.

I tried following steps from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733896/find-all-solutions-to-x9-equiv-25mod-29).

So we get:

$$y^{40} \equiv 2 \pmod {79}   \implies   (y^{40})^2=y^{80} \equiv 2 \pmod {79}.$$

Now since $80$ gives remainder $1$ when divided by $\!\!\mod {79}$, then:
$$y^{80} \equiv y^{79} \cdot y\equiv y \pmod {79}.$$
Thus, $x=2$? I did a direct computational of $2^{40} \equiv 2 \pmod {79}$ and it does seem true.

Did I approach this correctly?

Comment: z = 2 mod(79) implies z^2 = 2 mod(79) how did you find this ? it should be 4 i think.

Comment: I was following the steps from another post similar to this one.

Comment: Exhaustive search is one answer.... mainly consider that you can easily compute $x^k$ for large $k$ mod $m$ thanks to the properties of exponents mod $m$....

Comment: For the last step, did you deduce that y^79= 1 mod(79) ? because y^79= y mod(79) and y*y^79= y^2 mod(79).

Comment: Note:  $y^{79}\equiv y \pmod {79}$ by Fermat's Little Theorem/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic idea is sound, but there are a number of arithmetic errors in your calculation.  A corrected version would be something like:

$$x^{40}\equiv 2 \implies x^{80}\equiv 4\implies x^2\equiv 4\implies x\equiv \pm 2$$

Where every congruence is $\pmod {79}$.

Comment: So the solution would be actually $\pm$ 2? But would my steps still hold or do I have to rewrite everything?

Comment: Yes you got (part of) the correct solution but you did so by making two separate mistakes which cancelled out.  So, yes, you need to rewrite.

Comment: Oh okay I see, but my solution was wrong in the sense that I didn't get the negative 2 right?

Comment: Yes, you said that $x\equiv 2$ where the correct answer is $\pm 2$.  But, really, the more important point is the algebra involved in getting there.  It looks (to me) like just an odd coincidence that the two mistakes happened to conspire to produce part of the correct answer.

Comment: I will check on it, I was doing in a rush, but I will fix it. Thank you very much

Comment: 2 and -2 are just preliminary solutions, the set is larger.

Comment: @Abra001  the solutions are $\pm 2 \pmod {79}$.

Comment: ah ok got it. thanks.